# 100V LED signaling

Tags: led, pcb-design, circuit-design, power-electronics, design-rules

I am working on a device that will convert 4,5–100V into 3v3. It is done with a DC/DC regulator.

I want to use LEDs to signal that input is plugged in and that 3v3 is also available.

- What is the proper way?
- How can I avoid damaging the first diode?
- Will D1 light with 100V and also with 30V?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHhpqt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: do you require D1 to light all the way to V1=4.5V or just 30V? This is unclear from your question and decisive for the solution. Impressive input range DC/DC converter though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You show a 4.7k resistor for the high voltage side LED.

At 100V, that would be about 20 milliamperes to the LED.

At 30V, that will be about 6 milliamperes to the LED.

The LED will light in both cases.  A modern LED will still be very bright if operated on "just" 6 milliamperes.

There will, of course, be a noticeable difference in brightness between the two cases.

If that doesn't bother you, then the simple resistor circuit would work.

Keep in mind that you'll need a fairly hefty resistor.  At 100 volts, the resistor will have to dissipate something like 2 watts.  You'll need a resistor with an appropriate power rating.

A constant current source would make the brightness constant, but would still have to handle nearly the same amount of power.

With a constant current source, though, you could reduce the current.  With the resistor you have to allow more current at high voltage in order to get a decent brightness (at lower current) at low voltage.  With a constant current source you can set the current lower and have the same brightness at both voltage levels.

Answer (score 1):

A one- or two-transistor constant current source circuit will do exactly what you want - provide a constant current through the led regardless of the voltage across the circuit.  Note that standard small-signal transistors will not handle the power dissipation.  At 100 V and 20 mA through the LED, power dissipation in the current source circuit will be 2 W.

Here is a random innergoogle image grab of the circuit.  Q1 should be rated for at least 200 V and 5 W.

https://lednique.com/power-supplies/simple-constant-current-driver/

[image]

Comment: Red  LED still visible with small current, like 1-2 mA.

Comment: Is that good or bad?

Comment: Heat dissipating easier,  could be only 200mW max.

Answer (score 0):

How much hardware can you add? if you can add other chips, you can always create voltage divider with very high resistor values and feed it into the comparator. For example, you can take 1/33th of voltage (1k and 32k resistors), so 4.5V input will turn into something like 0.13V, and 100V will turn into 3.3V. Feed it into the comparator, comparing to 0.1V. Use capacitors on inputs. Comparator is powered by 3.3V, it should consume close to nothing. You can power it from transistor+resistor+zener makeshift linear regulator. Of course, make sure no parts will be exposed to voltages they can't take. Comparator output lights up the LED, of course, that was the whole point.

Wait a sec, when you're plugged in, you always have 3.3V output. You can't have input without output. Unless your DC/DC has enable pin. Which you can pull up from the same 3.3V makeshift linear regulator.

Btw, I'm pretty sure there is some linear regulator that can drop the voltage enough for comparator to work.

I think I have overcomplicated things, but this is a complete improvisation as I'm just writing this text.

Answer (score 0):

There's no passive solution that will work to light that LED over the range you're looking for. You need some kind of regulator, and it needs to have fairly low overhead to light a 3.3V LED (most are actually 2.8 ~ 3.1V.)

You have a couple of options.

- use an LDO with 100V input capability (but check the overhead to see if it will work down to 4.5V... it might not.)
- design a current mirror using BJTs or FETs to set the LED current.

The current mirror will be the most economical.